# I am getting errors when trying to load a Universal Windows App in the Visual Studio 2015 Simulator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am getting these errors when trying to load a Univeral Windows App in Visual Studio 2015 Community Simulator. I have followed the instructions in the errors but it still does not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using USB Dongle or USB Net connect then immediately disconnect it and try again. It should work fine.

Some times USB dongle reserve the port which port used by Simulator.
Then unplugged your Dongle or any other USB device run your Simulator and wish to plugin your USB devices.